# titlebar sticks when I change to an empty workspace ?

Tags: unity, workspaces, titlebar

this happens with any app not just chrome

I have chrome open and its normal to have its titlebar up up

[image]

now I change to a different (empty) workspace and chromes titlebar sticks only the app name is missing

[image]

I'm using `UBUNTU 17.04`

Answer (score 0):

this solved the problem

set `Icons on Desktop` in `Tweak tool` to `on` .

[image]